# VBA change Script on multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Via this forum I found a way to refresh autofilters in a table automatically after the data in a excel worksheet has changed, using this VBA script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Notes").ListObjects("Table1")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

But I actually would like two tables to be updated each time any data on the worksheet changes, is this possible and can anyone help me write te correct code please?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add it in based on the other table's name and WS, for instance:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Notes").ListObjects("Table1")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Notes").ListObjects("Table2")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Or combine it in any other way (depending on your data structure).